# How to prepare digital encrypted signature in android?

Tags: android, encryption

I am preparing one application.My application has one form . After filling all the fields in form need user signature.For signature i am planing use digital encrypted signature.I have no idea about digital encrypted signature.Please guide me and provide some tutorials .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bouncy castle library on the Android for the signing.

For a brief discussion on this you can look at this:

[How do I RSA encrypt a string with a plaintext key using Java BouncyCastle API on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234529/how-do-i-rsa-encrypt-a-string-with-a-plaintext-key-using-java-bouncycastle-api-o)

But, the bigger problem is to securely do the key exchange, as the RSA keypair is generated on the client or server and then sent securely to the other side (the private key stays on the device, so it should generate the keypair).

But, here is an example that shows signing with bouncy castle.

http://www.mobilefish.com/download/bouncycastle/DigitalSignature1Example.java

Answer (score 0):

Should take a look at the [Signing your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) documentation. You will be guided through the process of generating your encryption key, java keystore, and signing your application for Google Play submission

Comment: He is trying to prove that the correct user actually submitted the data, not signing his application.